# Cut multiples line between two strings

Tags: powershell

I have a code that it cuts a text lines between two characters. It works fine but I have two problems.

1. The blank lines are dropped.
2. When it find a `,` character it doesn't write nothing from `,` character at end of this line.

I put the character `¥` at the beginning and end of the text file to be cut.

This is the code:

```bsh
$messagesubjects=import-csv original.txt | Out-String
foreach($messagesubject in $messagesubjects) {         
    $start= $messagesubject.indexof("¥") +1
    $end= $messagesubject.indexof("¥",$start) 
    $length =$end - $start
    $messagesubjects.substring($start, $length) | out-file cutfile.txt -Append
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You know that `Import-Csv` expects a `comma delimited values` file? You should [edit] your question to contain your input and expected output.

Comment: Is `original.txt` a well-formatted .csv  file?

Comment: No, my original.txt is a textfile without any format. Hoy can i do this with a normal text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finded the solution. As you said was the way to read the file

```
$messagesubjects=[IO.File]::ReadAllText("original.txt")
```

Thanks